# Submit button and input validation?

Tags: javascript, button, character, submit

I would like to change this code to work also when Enter is pressed to be more clear i got an submit form and an text field following with the submit button that has to be clicked to submit but that doesn't help me out as i need the form to recognize when enter is pressed, what would be the change to sort it out?

```
submitButton.onclick = function() {
  index    = 0;
  results  = [];
  username = usernameInput.value;
  if ( username.length > 0 ) {
     window.location.href   = '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '#' + username;
     usernameInput.disabled = true;
     submitButton.disabled  = true;
     getExistence();
  }
```

Also i got an issue with input validation, what change should i made to allow the form recognize and accept special characters?

```
 usernameInput.onchange = function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/ig, '').slice(0, 40);


var urlUsername          = window.location.href.match(/\#([0-9a-z]{1,40})$/i)
```

I would ask from you to be more specific as i am new to javascript coding, and my knowledge it's not enough to sort it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First solution is to read this. 
https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/01/enter-should-submit-forms-stop-messing-with-that/

You get info why "button type="submit" is better way than adding that into JS.
I think, solution for your problem can be something like that:

```
<form>
    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="120" name="age" id="age">
    <button id="child">Child</button>
    <button id="adult">Adult</button>
</form>
<script>
    (function() {
        var age = document.getElementById('age');
        age.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (age.value > 20) {
                    document.getElementById('adult').click();
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('child').click();
                }
            }
        });
    }());
</script>
```

In short, commenting your code:

> submitButton.onclick = function() { ... your code

This work as you describe, onclick. You can have similar function with :

> submitButton.onkeypress = function() { ... same code with checking keyCode as example above

Validation: the simplest way to create any Regex is by doing some real test. I'am personally prefer this site: https://regex101.com/

What "**special**" character you mean? Because nobody can help right now. More info in this particular example. You just don't need any RegEx for JS. Accept any char and do everything on backend.

Comment: Thank you for your clean answer, for the second one the issue with the Regex was that i had included a call on my PHP site to block underscores and special characters.

`var urlUsername          = window.location.href.match(/\#([0-9a-z]{1,40})$/i);` i did replaced it with `var urlUsername          = window.location.href.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g);` after making the change on the code i had to delete the call on my PHP site to make it work.